# Translating english to morse-code with a for-loop

Tags: java, arrays

I've searched thoroughly but couldn't find a satisfactory answer on this site.
My task is to translate a string of english uppercase chars into morse-code.

My plan was to loop through the string and match the index of (i) in the array with letters with the index of the morse-code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Morse { 
    public static void main(String[]arg) {
        Scanner Read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String uinput, res = "";

        String[] Eng = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","X","Y","Z"};
        String[] mors = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};

        System.out.println("Ange den text du vill översätta till Morse-kod: ");
        uinput = Read.nextLine();  //uinput = user input 
        for (int i = 0; i < uinput.length(); ) {
            res = res + (mors.charAt(Eng.indexOf(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the error message:

```
Morse.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  res = res + (mors.charAt(Eng.indexOf(i)));
                                  ^
  symbol:   method indexOf(int)
  location: variable Eng of type String[]
1 error
```

Comment: Obviously, your problem is that you are trying to apply method `indexOf` to array instead of `String`.

Comment: `Eng` is a (poorly named) array of `String`s, not a `String`.  As such, it doesn't have a `indexOf` method which the compiler is informing you about.  You probably want to use a `Map`.

Comment: Look at the documentation for [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). It requires a char or a String as a parameter.

Comment: Try to use `HashMap` to do what you want. Arrays of strings are bad way.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

The first is that you're not looking at the characters from `uinput` itself. You need to iterate over these characters to build your output.

The second is that Java's array built-in does not have an indexOf() method. You have a few options to this one:

1. You can write one yourself.
2. You can put the contents of the Eng array into a List (probably an ArrayList), which does have the indexOf() method.
3. Since a Java char is also a number, you can use the letter itself as an index into the Morse Code array. (But beware of case issues, and be aware that the numeric value for 'A' is not 0.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use String methods on the array. I think the right approach would be to loop through the arrays and check each one for the character. That is, replace:

```
  for (int i=0; i<uinput.length();)
  {
  res = res + (mors.charAt(Eng.indexOf(i)));
  }
```

With something **like**:

```
for (int i=0; i<uinput.length(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<Eng.length(); j++){
        if(uipunt.charAt(i) == Eng[j]) {
           res = res + (mors[j]);
           continue;
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't tested but should hopefully put you on the right path

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are seeing is a result of calling a method that does not exist. Arrays are referenced using brackets []. To get index i we would say:

```
Eng[i]
```

Personally, I would deference the ASCII code to identify the index for the mores-code.  In this case, the letter "A" is 65 in ASCII. "A" is index zero in the array.  So the index the char's ASCII value (uppercase) minus 65.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MorseCode {

    private static final String[] MORS = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".",
            "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.",
            "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--",
            "-..-", "-.--", "--.." };

    public static void main(String... args) {

        try (Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            System.out.print("Morse-Code It (type \"exit\" to exit): ");

            String text = "";
            while (!"exit".equals(text.toLowerCase())) {
                text = removeNonLetters(read.nextLine());
                System.out.println(toMors(text));
            }
        }
    }

    private static String removeNonLetters(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
    }

    private static int getIndex(char c) {
        return Character.toUpperCase(c)-65;
    }

    private static String toMors(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(MORS[getIndex(str.charAt(i))]);
            sb.append("   ");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

charAt is not a valid method to call on a string array. Use an ArrayList instead of array's and you should be able to use index of.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you all for your answers, they helped me in creating the final code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Morse
{ 
 public static void main(String[]arg)
 {
  Scanner Read = new Scanner(System.in);
  String uinput,utskr = "";


  String[] letters = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","X","Y","Z"};
  String[] mors = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
  System.out.println("Ange den text du vill översätta till Morse-kod: ");
  uinput = Read.nextLine();
  for (int i=0; i<uinput.length();)
  {
  char currentChar = uinput.charAt(i);
  int charIndex = letters.indexOf(currentChar);
  utskr = utskr + mors[charIndex] + " ";
  }

  System.out.println(utskr);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestProgram {

    public static HashMap<String, String> alphaMorse = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        alphaMorse.put("A", ".-");
        alphaMorse.put("B", "-...");
        alphaMorse.put("C", "-.-.");
        alphaMorse.put("D", "-..");
        alphaMorse.put("E", ".");
        alphaMorse.put("F", "..-.");
        alphaMorse.put("G", "--.");
        alphaMorse.put("H", "....");
        alphaMorse.put("I", "..");
        alphaMorse.put("J", ".---");
        alphaMorse.put("K", "-.-");
        alphaMorse.put("L", ".-..");
        alphaMorse.put("M", "--");
        alphaMorse.put("N", "-.");
        alphaMorse.put("O", "---");
        alphaMorse.put("P", ".--.");
        alphaMorse.put("Q", "--.-");
        alphaMorse.put("R", ".-.");
        alphaMorse.put("S", "...");
        alphaMorse.put("T", "-");
        alphaMorse.put("U", "..-");
        alphaMorse.put("V", "...-");
        alphaMorse.put("W", ".--");
        alphaMorse.put("X", "-..-");
        alphaMorse.put("y", "-.--");
        alphaMorse.put("z", "--..");
        alphaMorse.put("1", ".----");
        alphaMorse.put("2", "..---");
        alphaMorse.put("3", "...--");
        alphaMorse.put("4", "....-");
        alphaMorse.put("5", ".....");
        alphaMorse.put("6", "-....");
        alphaMorse.put("7", "--...");
        alphaMorse.put("8", "---..");
        alphaMorse.put("9", "----.");
        alphaMorse.put("0", "-----");
        alphaMorse.put(" ", "|");

        String st = "hello";

    String morse="";
        String convertedMorseCode=toMors(st);
        System.out.print(convertedMorseCode);
    }

    public static String toMors(String st){
        String morse="";

        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
            char c =st.charAt(i);

            char charUpper = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            String morseCode= alphaMorse.get(Character.toString(charUpper));
            //System.out.println(morseCode);
            morse=  morse+morseCode;

        }
        return morse;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't handled edge case when user input is anything other than english characters